# What is the best way to format a function's return value to include spaces between variables?

Tags: python, function, format

Without making my foo function contain an actual print statement, and only have foo return a
value, what is the best way to format a function? The code in the example will make the main function print "11" for example, instead of "1 1" or "1 & 1".

I really appreciate ya'll!

```
def foo(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return x*2
            

def main():
    x=input("Enter value 1")
    y=input("Enter value 2")
    print(int(max(x,y)))


main()
```

Comment: You can do `print(f'{x} {y}')`. Also I have no idea what you're doing with `max` here. Both x and y are strings so max will return a single value of the string that has the highest ASCII value. Right now it won't print even what you think it prints. It will print `'1'`. Have you even ran this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the code that you've provided isn't matching your actual question (in the title), I'll try to answer what I *think* is your question.

You can try returning a string with a space in between the elements, like so:

```py
def foo(x,y): 
    if x == y:
        string = str(x)+" "+str(y) #there's a space between the quotation marks
        return string
        #this works even if x and y are not integers due to `str(x)` & `str(y)`
```

Another approach is:

```py
def foo(x,y):
    if x==y:
        n = 2 #this is the number of times you want x to appear in the output
        x_new = x+" " #x concatenated with a space
        return (x_new*n).rstrip()
        #here, rstrip() is a string method that removes\
        #whitespaces from the *right* end of the string
```

The advantage of concatenation of strings is that you can concatenate any character (or string!) to `str(x)`. For example, you can return `str(x)+"&"+str(y)` and you'll get `1&1` for x=1!
In the image below, I have defined `foo(x,y)` thrice and then printed the value returned by the function. NOTE: This is in the interactive Python IDLE Shell. 
[image: Python IDLE Shell Image]